# segmentation fault error in C using strcpy

Tags: c

```
char** key;

strcpy(*key, "Hello");
strcpy(*(key+1), "World");

printf("%s", *key);
```

The second `strcpy` has no error, while the first `strcpy` has a segmentation fault. How should I modify to achieve the original purpose?

Comment: Uh. Is this the whole of your code? You haven't initialized key to point to anything. So its an uninitialized pointer that you are dereferencing to char* to pass to strcpy.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is Undefined Behavior.

```
char * strcpy ( char * destination, const char * source )
```

[strcpy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) expects a destination which can be modified. You are passing a `char **` which is causing the problem since you have not allocated any memory for it to write to.

This is what (perhaps) you were trying:

```
  char* key = malloc(sizeof(char)*7); // 7 because it can Hold World with a Nul character

  strcpy(key, "Hello");
  strcpy((key+1), "World");

  printf("%s", key);
```

Comment: would you please explain a little bit more?

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is always redundant when used like this, it is *defined by the C standard* to be 1.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear in your code whether you are allocating any buffer for key. I believe that's why you are getting SEG fault.

Answer (score 0):

You must allocate memory to before you do `strcpy()`, if you want to skip allocating memory try `strdup()`.

To simplify, not sure you really want `char **key`, doing with `char *key`

```
char* key = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100); //allocate to store 100 chars
strcpy(key, "Hello");
strcpy(key + strlen(key), "World");
//or strcat(key, "World");
```

> the second strcpy has no error, while the first strcpy has a segmentation fault

How do you know 2nd one does not have error when it never executed because of segmentation fault?

Answer (score 0):

No memory has been allocated for `key`.  You can allocate memory using `malloc` before the first `strcpy`.

```
*key = malloc(32 * sizeof(char));     // pick a size of buffer
```

I suspect the second call will also cause a segfault.  It's (probably) going to be writing into unallocated space.

Comment: @DennisMeng Good point, I read the code incorrectly.